# PHP5-FPM (PHP 5.5) won't install - can't install libsystemd-daemon0

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, php, php-fpm

My server is down because I don't know how to fix this. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 I use this PHP5 repository: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu precise main

I've never had a problem until today. A few hours ago, I did an apt-get upgrade and everything went fine until it reached the PHP5-FPM portion:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-fpm : Depends: libsystemd-daemon0 (>= 31) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install `libsystemd-daemon0` but I get a notice that it has no installation candidate. Can someone tell me how to fix this without me pulling what's left of my hair out?

Comment: Fixed it: wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/systemd/libsystemd-daemon0_44-12_amd64.deb .. dpkg -i *.deb .. 
apt-get install php5-fpm

Answer (score 2):

For anyone (like me) who encountered this and used the repository `ppa:ondrej/php5`, you'll need their `systemd` repository as well to get this with `apt-get`.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/systemd
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get install -y php5-fpm
```

Comment: JFTR It's written in the PPA description, but it's impossible to communicate this to people already using the PPA.

Comment: See my answer below, this is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 2):

From this moment, the solution should very easy, just do:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Since it seems that adding another PPAs is too complicated, I have merged all necessary packages into the main repository, so this should not happen anymore.

Edit: JFTR the php5-fpm no longer depends on any systemd component, so it can be installed without the hassle of pulling libsystemd-daemon0.

Comment: Thanks! One less thing to worry about in deploy scripts.

Comment: With the latest update, on precise I get php5-fpm : Depends: sysv-rc (>= 2.88dsf-24) but 2.88dsf-13.10ubuntu11 is to be installed or
                     file-rc (>= 0.8.16) but it is not installable

Comment: @D-Rock Working on that, it should be fixed in next build of php5.

Comment: @D-Rock This has been fixed in 5.5.1+dfsg-2+debphp.org~<dist>+2, the php5-fpm package no longer depends on neither systemd nor too new sysv-rc.

Answer (score 0):

Tedders solution works perfectly.

There's one detail, however, for those who had a working Geo IP PHPFPM support and it broke with the update.

To restore GeoIP functionality:

```
pecl install geoip
```

Then cd to /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d and add a 20-geoip.ini file with this content:

```
; configuration for php geoip module
extension=geoip.so
```

The upgrade also (re)sets to zero some settings that are useful for PHPFPM high availability:

```
emergency_restart_threshold = 5
emergency_restart_interval = 2
process_control_timeout = 2
```

Comment: The package is there, but it's overridden by the package in the main Ubuntu repository (for Ubuntu raring).  Right now you need to either use apt pinning (man apt_preferences) or manually install the php5-geoip package from the repository.  I will think of the way how to override default Ubuntu package in meanwhile.

Comment: This should be also OK now, since the php-geoip packages' version is now higher than main Ubuntu version of php-geiop.